# SSRS - Pause a schedule systematically?

Tags: reporting-services, schedule

I have a few schedules that run nightly but they depend on background processes to ensure the data is ready to go.

Is there an easy way to set a flag that I could disable a job if a table value isn't set to a parameter?

My thoughts are a basic table with "Status" as a column. If Status=1 then run. If not Pause the schedule.

There doesn't seem to be a lot to read about SSRS scheduling besides the GUI interface.

Thanks
~J

Answer (score 0):

the reports should not start at a given time, nor paused or whatever. they should be called from within your data processing process, after you've processed the underlying data.

there's plenty of ways to start subsciptions, one being the ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent procedure (just google for it).